# How do you generate a motion plan from moveit_msgs::MotionPlanRequest and moveit_msgs::MotionPlanResponse?

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, motionplanning

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use the Pilz Industrial Motion Planner in a C++ node and the tutorials claim that it uses `moveit_msgs::MotionPlanRequest` (and Response) but I haven't found a way to actually generate the plan to populate the response. The Motion Planning Pipeline tutorial uses `planning_interface::MotionPlanRequest` (and Response) and generates the plans using `planning_pipeline::PlanningPipeline (name_of_pipeline)` and `name_of_pipeline->generatePlan`. Is there something similar I could use for the `moveit_msgs::MotionPlanRequest`?
I tried using the planning pipeline method with Pilz and it worked for a single trajectory, but I don't think there is a way I can use `moveit_msgs::MotionSequenceRequest` this way which is ultimately the tool I want to use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400193/how-do-you-generate-a-motion-plan-from-moveit_msgs::motionplanrequest-and-moveit_msgs::motionplanresponse?/) by [ASPHassan](https://answers.ros.org/users/104226/asphassan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I found the answer and I'll share it here in case anyone finds it helpful. The [Pilz Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/pilz_industrial_motion_planner/pilz_industrial_motion_planner.html) gives you two options: The MoveGroup Action and the `/plan_kinematic_path` service. Both of these should start up when you start the `movegroup` node. I used the `/plan_kinematic_path` to generate a PILZ trajectory and the movegroup interface to execute that trajectory. It seems that this should work with other planning plugins, or atleast ones that develop kinematic paths. i.e

---

```
moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::Plan plan; 
moveit_msgs::MotionPlanRequest req;
moveit_msgs::MotionPlanResponse res;
```

Fill out the request as shown in the tutorial.
I formed the goal constraints using

```
moveit_msgs::Constraints pose_start_goal = kinematic_constraints::constructGoalConstraints(end_link, pose_stamped, tolerance_pos, tolerance_ang);
```

and then I instantiated the service client, filled the request and called the service:

```
ros::ServiceClient motionplanclient = nh.serviceClient<moveit_msgs::GetMotionPlan>("/plan_kinematic_path");
plan_path.waitForExistence();
moveit_msgs::GetMotionPlan motionplansrv;
motionplansrv.request.motion_plan_request = req;
motionplanclient.call(motionplansrv);
```

Then I pulled the response from the service and added the trajectory to the plan

```
res=motionplansrv.response.motion_plan_response;
plan.trajectory_=res.trajectory;
```

I used rviz_visual_tools to publish the trajectory `visual_tools.publishTrajectoryLine(plan.trajectory_, joint_model_group)` and `move_group.execute(plan)` to move the robot.

My current issue is now with MotionSequenceRequest, namely visualizing the path in RVIZ and executing the plan, but I'll post that as another question and link it [here.](https://answers.ros.org/question/400573/visualizing-a-motion-sequence-in-rviz-and-executing-that-sequence-using-the-move_group_interface-in-a-c-node/)

---

Originally posted by [ASPHassan](https://answers.ros.org/users/104226/asphassan/) with karma: 11 on 2022-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1